# Moving a photo but have it invisible

Tags: html, css

I have I'm trying to move photos on [this page](http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/).

To the far right which I used `float: right;` and that seems okay but if you notice it's pushing the Products Name test field down. I don't know how to make that field come back up as well as have the photo off to the right of the page.

I am using `Magento` Shopping Cart so I don't know how to post this hoping maybe someone could visit the page and see the `CSS` and what I am doing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now define your `ul` `float:left` as like this

```
#advanced-search-list {
float: left;
}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make your `span` (which wraps the image) as:

```
display: inline-block;
float: right;
```

Make your `ul` (advanced-search-list) as:

```
float: left;
```